# How to get the GROUP BY where the lowest value is the one shown

Tags: mysql, group-by

So I have these 3 value that has the same `product_id` and I'm grouping them by `product_id` in my query but I want the one that's returned to be the one with the lowest price. So, in this case, it would display the `Impact Diet Whey (Amostra) - 60g - Natural Baunilha` instead of `Alcool Gel`

My DB:
[image]

My current query:

```
SELECT * FROM products_data.retailers GROUP BY product_id
```

I tried `ORDER_BY price` but still displays the `Alcohol Gel` first and only orders the full result by the price

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you `GROUP BY` a few `product_id` and you want to know which have the lowest price. One way you can achieve that is by making a sub-query with `MIN(price)` grouped by `product_id` then joined with the table again to get each product_id that have the lowest price. Consider this query example:

```
SELECT B.* FROM
(SELECT product_id,MIN(price) min_price FROM products GROUP BY product_id) A
JOIN products B
ON A.product_id=B.product_id 
AND A.min_price=B.price;
```

Since this join is on `product_id` and `price`, it means that if a `product_id` have more than 1 with lowest price, it will return everything correspond to the lowest price and `product_id`. You can refer to this fiddle example : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7pHTqTDYpbEEwViy71P5F4/0

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to `SELECT *` when grouping by product_id. This query is invalid and should raise an error, because it requests the DBMS to show *the* currency, *the* shipping, *the* rating ... for a product, but there ain't just one currency, one shipping, one rating for a product in the table (or at least this isn't guaranteed to be the case).

If MySQL doesn't raise an exception, then you are using an old version without `sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'`. Use this setting until you understand what `GROUP BY` does.

To get the row with the lowest price, order by price and limit to one row:

```
SELECT *
FROM products_data.retailers
ORDER BY price
LIMIT 1;
```

On a side note: You may want to make sure you only compare prices of the same currency.

Comment: @Marios Karamanis: Read my answer. I have mentioned this problem. I don't know whether there exists a price conversion table in the database though, so I cannot say which would be the best solution for this; I can only mention that this is an issue. So rather than downvoting, you may want to upvote, because I have spotted this issue and mentioned it in my answer.